# Android: Launching Library Activity from Main App

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-library

i already readed the "similar questions" but i'm still not able to launch the Library Project Activity from the Main Project.

I have project A (Main)
and i have project B (library)

Activity is declared in the library manifest (even in main manifest)

but when i run the code the log throws the error that ask if activity is declared in manifest.xml file.

Main Project is rightly including the library, everything compiles but the error is that, i put the intent i'm trying from main project:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.activities", "MyActivity"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setPackage(context.getPackageName()); // tried without this
context.startActivity(intent);
```

this is my manifest (from library project):

```
<activity
        android:name="com.package.activities.MyActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

Log:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.package.activities/MyActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: try intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.activities", "com.package.activities.MyActivity"));

Comment: i gonna try and i comment

Comment: same result with this one

Comment: HI Ninja, Did you solve this issue..am also facing this same situation..

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: this is not allowed, when i use this code, the compilation fails "Cannot resolve symbol MyActivity" when i use quick fix from Android Studio (Alt+Enter) options are: "Add dependency..." (i clicked that option but nothing happens) and "Move MyActivity from module (library) to (main)" but this is not the wished one. We need to keep Activity in library.

Comment: It sounds like your library project isn't being included correctly into the main project then. Can you paste a copy of your app/build.gradle file?

Comment: You are right, the project isn't being included correctly, because it's trying to build with gradle-experimental in a main project with gradle-stable. It looks like both are not compatibles. and Gradle(stable) can't attach module with Gradle (experimental).

Comment: there is a fix for that case?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, I haven't ever tried doing that.  If you really need to mix them, you might want to post a new question specifically about that. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you try to launch the activity as a separate component, Android starts looking for this library activity within your main project code. As the activity belongs to the library and not the main project, you get the `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Given that you have added the library project as an AAR file to the main project, you can simply launch the library activity from the main project as follows:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, "your.library.package.activityname.class")
startActivity(intent)
```

You must declare the library activity in the manifest file of your main project. A single line should suffice

```
<application ...>
    <activity android:name="your.library.package.activityname" />
</application>
```